# React Native - How do i get rid off of Warning "Cannot update a component from inside the function body..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've search all similar issues on `Stackoverflow` something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526786/react-warning-cannot-update-a-component-from-inside-the-function-body-of-a-diff), but I have a different problem since that question is asking to call `parent` function from `child` component

Here's the code I've tried:

```
export default ()=>{
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(new Reanimated.Value(0));
  const scale = Reanimated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });
  const animatedStyle = { borderRadius, transform: [{ scale }] };
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'black'}}>
        <Drawer.Navigator
          {...anotherProps}
          drawerContent={props=>{
            setProgress(props.progress); //Here the Warning appears
            return <CustomDrawer {...props}/>
          }}
        >
          <Drawer.Screen name="Drawer">
            {StackNavigatorScreen}
          </Drawer.Screen>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Anyone can help what should I do with my current code to make this warning disappear?

> Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Comment: change setStatte to const progress = new Animated.Value(0) and in drawer content put progress.setValue(props.progress)

Comment: @AshwithSaldanha that method let the animation laggy